# Prove: if $n$ is a positive integer, then $n^2$ is divisible by 3 with remainder either $0$ or $1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would like a proofreading of my proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62831/would-like-a-proofreading-of-my-proof)

Prove that if $n$ is positive integer, then $n^2$ is divisible by $3$ with remainder either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: [a duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/62831/11619)

Comment: @evodevo: Don't take it personally that this is being closed. A house rule. I'm sure you will learn enough by studying the answers of the duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$
0^2=0\mod 3,
$$

$$
1^2=1\mod 3,
$$

$$
2^2=4=1\mod 3.
$$

Comment: So basically, your proof would be the above, except you would omit the word "hint" and replace "Use that" with "Since" :)

Comment: (As the answer originally appeared...+1, btw)

Comment: I turned my answer into something that is more like a hint and less like a full answer.