# Find all positive integers such that the set {n, n+ 1, n+ 2, n+ 3, n+ 4, n+ 5} can be partitioned into two subsets so that...[Full Q. Below]

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

> Find all positive integers such that the set {n, n+ 1, n+ 2, n+ 3, n+ 4, n+ 5} can be partitioned into two subsets so that the product of the numbers in each subset is equal

**My Approach:**

Well to be honest, I couldn't think of anything, I tried a few cases but they didn't prove to be any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [product of the numbers in each subset is equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164528/product-of-the-numbers-in-each-subset-is-equal)

Comment: It would be valuable to work $n=1$. Then you can eliminate several possibilities for all $n$ after working $\pmod p$ for low values of $p\ge 2$.